# I was trying to solve this question on GFG. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: arrays, matrix, data-structures, queue, dynamic-programming

[Geek's Journey](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/job-a-thon-21-hiring-challenge/problems)

> You're provided with two arrays:
>
> "geeksTown" of length n - representing the heights of buildings in
> Geek's town "journey" of length m      - representing the heights of
> buildings he sees during his train journey. Geek finds happiness when
> he encounters a series of buildings during his journey that completely
> match with geeksTown.
>
> You have 'q' queries of the form [l, r], where you need to determine
> how many times Geek will feel happy during the journey  from [l, r].
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: n = 4, geeksTown[] = {3, 0, 1, 9}, m = 11, journey[] = {1, 3,
> 0, 1, 9, 1, 7, 3, 0, 1, 9}, q = 4, queries[] = [  [0, 3],  [1, 5],
> [1, 10],  [7, 9] ] Output: 0 1 2 0
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: n = 2, geeksTown[] = {2, 2}, m = 6, journey[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2}, q = 3, queries[] = [ [0, 2], [1, 4], [0, 5] ] Output: 2 3 5

```
class Solution {
    public int[] geeksJourney(int geeksTown[], int n, int journey[], int m, int queries[][], int q) {
        Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < n; i++) {
            deque.addLast(journey[i]);
        }

        boolean dp[] = new boolean[m];

        while(i < m) {
            int j = 0;
            if (deque.peek() == geeksTown[j]) {
                while (j < n && deque.peek() == geeksTown[j]) {
                    deque.removeFirst();
                    if(i<m)deque.add(journey[i]);
                    j++;
                    i++;
                    if (j == n) dp[i-n] = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                deque.removeFirst();
                deque.addLast(journey[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        int[] ans = new int[q];
        for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            int l = queries[i][0]+n-1;
            int r = queries[i][1];
            int count = 0;
            while(l<=r)
            {
                if(dp[l]==true)count++;
                l++;
            }
            ans[i] = count;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

[Geek's Journey](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/job-a-thon-21-hiring-challenge/problems)

I used the deque as a sliding window and stored last index of the matching window in the dp.
Please tell what is wrong with this one and also please suggest other approches to solve this one.

Comment: [Geek's Journey](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/job-a-thon-21-hiring-challenge/problems) https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/job-a-thon-21-hiring-challenge/problems

Comment: Please paste (rather than link to) the problem you are trying to solve. Also provide the test case(s) where it is failing and what the expected vs actual outputs are.